# Brett aged beer - bottling?

Tags: bottle-conditioning, brettanomyces

I brewed an APA last year, and decided to keep a gallon or so aside and pitch some brett into it. 9 months later, I bottled it with a carbination drop, and a week later (I'm impatient OK?) there's still zero carbination. Is there a chance I might need to add a bit of extra yeast to carbonate, or is it that the brett is a bit slower to work with the carbination drop? Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use real Brett Or Faux Brett (Saccharomyces "Bruxellensis" Trois)?

In either case it's probably dead or very weak, usually the Brett is added at the time of bottling.

Repitch your bottles

Comment: Yeah, it was brett B - alongside the dregs from a bottle of Crooked Stave Wild Sage. Repitching and recapping sounds like it might be a goer then.

Comment: I guess the natural follow on question here is what strain would you recommend using? Should I use champagne yeast, or will a bog-standard ale yeast do the trick? Can I just drop a pinch of dried yeast in, or will I have to make a starter?

Comment: @Pezholio if the funk profile from your Brett is sufficient you can just use Champaign yeast, if not use more brux